# How do I grab arithmetic function from textbox in a spreadsheet program where textboxes are cells?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have created a spreadsheet program which displays a 26 by 26 grid of textboxes. I have created a custom class called Cell which inherits textbox and includes other properties such as cellID and isFormula. Cells which start with '=' are formulas. I have already created a method to grab the range in the cell such that I know which cells are to be used in the arithmetic funtions. For example, if the cell contents are: =A1:A3 + B1:B3, the method knows it is working with A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3. But how do I grab the operator and use it to carry out the function?

```
       public static void GetArithmeticFunctionRange(Cell selectedCell)
       {
        List<string> cellRange = new List<string>();
        string arithmeticFunction = selectedCell.Text;
        arithmeticFunction = arithmeticFunction.Replace(" ","").Trim();
        string[] subranges = arithmeticFunction.Split('+','-','*','/');
        string tempRange = "";
        char lowerBoundLetter;
        char upperBoundLetter;
        int lowerBoundNumber = 0;
        int upperBoundNumber = 0;

           for(int i = 0; i < subranges.Length; i++){
            tempRange = subranges[i];
            if(tempRange.Contains(":")){
                string[] rangeBounds = tempRange.Split(':');
                lowerBoundLetter = rangeBounds[0][0];
                upperBoundLetter = rangeBounds[1][0]; 
                lowerBoundNumber =int.Parse(rangeBounds[0].Substring(1));
                upperBoundNumber =int.Parse(rangeBounds[1].Substring(1));
                for (char columnLetter = lowerBoundLetter; columnLetter 
                <= upperBoundLetter; columnLetter++){
                    for (int rowNumber = lowerBoundNumber; rowNumber <= 
                upperBoundNumber; rowNumber++)
                    {
                        string cell = Convert.ToString(columnLetter) + 
                Convert.ToString(rowNumber);
                        cellRange.Add(cell);
                }
             }
          }
            else
                {
                cellRange.Add(tempRange);
                }
       }    

      }
```

Comment: First, you should break the formula up into tokens. You're very much building a rudimentary compiler and execution engine. It's not a trivial task.

Comment: Ok noted will do. Any suggestions for the grabbing of the arithmetic function?

Comment: You start with [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) which is the tokenization process. One (or more if you can do something like A1+A2+A3) of the tokens will end up being the operator. I think doing some research on compiler/interpreter design will take you a long way in your endeavor.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help.